Jest test failing due to initial null values
I'm preparing a test for a page on my website in NextJS, and in that page I'm supposed to be doing a fetch call to an /api route by means of a hook. This route executes a query that fetches data from a SQLite database, which is then returned to the page to populate it with the data. My page looks like this:
'use client';

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import AssetButton from '@/components/AssetButton';
import AssetInfo from '@/components/AssetInfo';
import AssetLogo from '@/components/AssetLogo';
import AssetScreenshot from '@/components/AssetScreenshot';
import Details from '@/components/Details';
import Loader from '@/components/Loader';
import Page from '@/components/Page';
import Text from '@/components/Text';
import useFetchData from '@/hooks/useFetchData';
import { Asset } from '@/utils/types';

export default function ProgramDetails() {
  const params = useParams();
  const { id } = params;

  const {
    data: program,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useFetchData<Asset>(`/api/programs/${id}`);

  const errorData = <p>{error}</p>;

  const isDownload = !program?.link?.includes('https://');

  return (
    <Page>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        errorData
      ) : (
        <>
          <AssetLogo icon={program!.icon} />
          <Text content={program!.name?.toUpperCase()} type="title" />
          <Text content={program!.description} type="body" />
          <AssetInfo>
            <AssetScreenshot file={program!.icon} />
            <Details details={program!.details?.split(';')} />
          </AssetInfo>
          <AssetButton isDownload={isDownload} link={program!.link} />
        </>
      )}
    </Page>
  );
}

Where I use the useFetchData hook to be able to tell when the api call is loading and when it gets data, so I can render a loader while the data is fetched. The hook looks like this:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetchData = <T>(url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(async (res) => {
          const data = await res.json();

          if (data) {
            setData(data);
          } else {
            setError('An unknown error has occurred');
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err.message);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetchData;

and the api route /api/programs/[id] looks like this:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import openDb from '@/utils/db';

export async function GET(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } },
) {
  const db = openDb();
  const { id } = params;
  const program = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE id = ?').get(id);

  if (!program) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Program not found' }, { status: 404 });
  }

  return NextResponse.json(program);
}

so the test is meant to mock a fetch call to return dummy data and check that the dummy data renders:
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import ProgramDetails from '@/app/programs/[id]/page';
import { ViewportProvider } from '@/context/ViewportContext';

const mockProgramData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Program 1',
    icon: 'icon1.png',
    description: 'Description for Program 1',
    details: ['detail 1', 'detail 2'],
    link: '/downloads/test.zip',
  },
];

jest.mock('next/navigation', () => ({
  useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: '1' }),
}));

describe('Program Details Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(mockProgramData),
      }),
    ) as jest.Mock;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('renders the program title, description, and details correctly', async () => {
    render(
      <ViewportProvider>
        <ProgramDetails />
      </ViewportProvider>,
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByTestId('triple-spinner')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    const title = await screen.findByTestId('text-title');
    expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(title).toHaveTextContent(mockProgramData[0].name);

    const body = await screen.findByTestId('text-body');
    expect(body).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(body).toHaveTextContent(mockProgramData[0].description);

    await waitFor(() => {
      mockProgramData[0].details.forEach((currDetail) => {
        expect(screen.getByText(currDetail)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText(currDetail)).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
    });
  });
});

at first I was assuming that, waiting for the loader's test id to not render would be enough to ensure the data is rendering. Just in case the loader looks like this:
import styles from './Loader.module.css';

const Loader: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div data-testid="loader" id={styles.loader}>
      <div
        className={styles['triple-spinner']}
        data-testid="triple-spinner"
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader;

Then, I would get the other elements by test id exist, and check if the text has rendered and matches. The Text component that has these ids is this:
import styles from './Text.module.css';

interface TextProps {
  content: string;
  type: 'body' | 'card' | 'hero' | 'modal' | 'title';
}

const Text: React.FC<TextProps> = ({ content, type }) => {
  return type === 'title' ? (
    <h3 className={styles[type]} data-testid="text-title">
      {content}
    </h3>
  ) : (
    <p className={styles[type]} data-testid="text-body">
      {content}
    </p>
  );
};

export default Text;

But as I run the test, I get this error:
expect(element).toHaveTextContent()

    Expected element to have text content:
      Program 1
    Received:

      45 |     const title = await screen.findByTestId('text-title');
      46 |     expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();
    > 47 |     expect(title).toHaveTextContent(mockProgramData[0].name);
         |                   ^
      48 |
      49 |     const body = await screen.findByTestId('text-body');

Since nothing shows, I tried printing the results of the fetch call in the hook, and I saw two iterations: one where the returned data is null, and another with the test data. So what I appear to need is to be able to skip that first call to ensure I can work with the actual returned data, but how can I accomplish that?

Change json: () => Promise.resolve(mockProgramData), to json: () => Promise.resolve(mockProgramData[0]),

Thank you, that worked! I guess I was returning the wrong type (Asset array instead of Asset), and maybe I didn't see in the console logs that the returned data from the fetch was an array, hence the undefined stuff.

As @hoangdv mentioned, the simple fix for this was to change the mock return data:
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(mockProgramData[0]),
      }),
    ) as jest.Mock;

Instead, I was returning mockProgramData, and I hadn't realized the logs I wrote from the hook's fetch call was returning an array:

This was the issue, as the page component wouldn't destructure the Asset element properly, giving the appearance of receiving the undefined data as first returned by the fetch call on initial render.
